# Generic constraint for COM object

Tags: c#, generics, com, dispose

I have a generic base class that wraps COM objects and want to constrain it to COM objects.
I tried `where TComObject : IUnknown` but the compiler does not like it. Is there a way to do this?

I use the code below, please give feedback if you spot something stupid.

```
public abstract class ComWrapper<TComObject> : IDisposable, IComWrapper<TComObject> where TComObject : class 
{
    protected ComWrapper(TComObject comObject)
    {
        ComObject = comObject;
    }

    protected TComObject ComObject { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use with caution, this accesses the COM object, cleanup might be needed
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public TComObject GetComObject()
    {
        return ComObject;
    }

    public void SetComObject(TComObject comObject)
    {
        CheckAndReleaseComObject();
        ComObject=comObject;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // free managed resources
        }
        // free native resources if there are any.
        CheckAndReleaseComObject();
    }

    private void CheckAndReleaseComObject()
    {
        if (ComObject != null)
        {
            if (ComObject.GetType().IsCOMObject)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ComObject);
            ComObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only is the finalizer pointless, it will crash your program.

Comment: @HansPassant why will it crash the program? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set such generic constraint, you could, however, consider using something like `Marshal.IsComObject` to ensure the object is a COM object. If you specifically want a compile time error, I think you're out of luck.

Also, note that SetComObject can be called multiple times, in which case you don't "clean up" any com object that may already have been set. Also, you can now remove GC.SuppressFinalize, as you removed your finalizer/destructor, which is indeed not needed because the framework will release the com object for you if it would get to a garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you, updated my code again. I already use ComObject.GetType().IsCOMObject before releasing for the cases when I pass a mock as ComObject (up voted)